# Why do i get segmentation fault 11?

Tags: c, function

Why do I get segmentation fault 11? I get it quite often, and I know this time it is about the function. If anyone can help, please do, the code is down below! I am trying to make a program, that WITH A FUNCTION, can rearrange an array in ascending order and then print it in main in reverse order.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void changxr(int *counter, int *arrsize, int *j, int *arr[]);

int main()
{
    int a, i, j, counter;
    int arrsize;
    int arr[100];
    printf("pick an arraysize: \n");
    scanf("%d", &arrsize);
    printf("type %d numbers \n", arrsize);
    for (counter = 0; counter < arrsize; counter++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[counter]);
    }

    for (int c = arrsize - 1; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[c]);
    }

    changxr(&counter, &arrsize, &j, &arr[&counter]);

    for (counter = arrsize - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[counter]);
    }
}

void changxr(int *counter, int *arrsize, int *j, int *arr[])
{
    int a;
    for (*counter = 0; *counter < *arrsize; *counter++)
    {
        for (*j = *counter + 1; *j < *arrsize; *j++)
        {
            if (*arr[*counter] > *arr[*j])
            {
                a = *arr[*counter];
                *arr[*counter] = *arr[*j];
                *arr[*j] = a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

New code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

void changxr(int arrsize, int *arr[]);

int main()
{
    int a, i, j, counter;
    int arrsize;
    int arr[100];
    printf("pick an arraysize: \n");
    scanf("%d", &arrsize);

    printf("type %d numbers \n", arrsize);
    for (counter = 0; counter < arrsize; counter++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[counter]);
    }

    for (int c = arrsize - 1; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[c]);
    }

    changxr(arrsize, &arr[counter]);

    for (counter = arrsize - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[counter]);
    }
}

void changxr(int arrsize, int *arr[])
{
    int a, counter, j;
    for (counter = 0; counter < arrsize; counter++)
    {
        for (j = counter + 1; j < arrsize; j++)
        {
            if (*arr[counter] > *arr[j])
            {
                a = *arr[counter];
                *arr[counter] = *arr[j];
                *arr[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I got from debugging:

```
"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555555355 in changxr (arrsize=3, arr=0x0) at main.c:33
33              for(j=counter+1; j<arrsize; j++) { if(*arr[counter]>*arr[j]){
(gdb) continue"
```

Comment: Best advice: Now would be a good time to learn to use a debugger. It will instantly tell you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. Can also do many other things such as step thru the code line by line to examine the variables and code flow as it runs.

Comment: `&arr[&counter]` looks very wrong. `&counter` is an address so why would it make sense to use it as an index? Not sure what exactly you are trying to do there. Should pass in just `arr` and then the function param should be declared as `int *arr`.

Comment: `changxr(&counter, &arrsize, &j, &arr[&counter]);`  That's overly complicated. You don't need to pass in `counter` and `j`. You are only using those as local variables in the function so just declare them as such inside the function. And `arrsize` is never changed inside the function so just pass it in as an `int` rather than a pointer.

Comment: i did, but I still need help with the seg fault 11

Comment: If you did then you should update the post with what debugging info you found. Such as the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault.

Comment: I did, Im quite new, so llow me. :)

Comment: That output is from the compiler and not the debugger. Anyway, `&arr[counter]` is still wrong. `&arr[counter]` is the address of the first invalid/unset entry in the array.  As I said, it needs to be called as `changxr(arrsize, arr);` with function defined as `changxr ( int arrsize, int *arr)`

Comment: But i dont understand, how can i *arr if I dont send the location. And arr[] is meant to be an array?

Comment: In C an array becomes a pointer when it is passed to a function. So in `changxr ( int arrsize, int *arr)` the second parameter can be an array. And that's exactly what you are passing to it when you give just `arr`. And you are not supposed to `*arr`. That's overly complicated. Just do `arr[counter]` inside the function.

Comment: Ohhhh, Thank you. By the way I think i put the actual debugging output in now.

Comment: Just to squelch the potential wild-guesses, [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70646670/edit) (not comments) should include the *purpose* of the code. I.e. what is it trying to accomplish, what are the expectations of output for a specific input (which you also provide, again, [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70646670/edit). It's important that we know what you're *trying* to do, as much as it is to know *how* you're trying to accomplish it. I expect a *ton* of this can be scrapped for much simpler code, depending on the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need two levels of indirection (`int *arr[]`, `*arr[counter]`, `*arr[j]`). When `arr` is passed to a function, it will decay to a pointer-to-its-first-element, or more simply, an `int *`.

`&arr[counter]` is also an `int *`, but it is the address of the array element one past the elements you've initialized. This would start your sorting function in the incorrect place.

Your program segfaults because it attempts to use this value as an `int **` (`int *[]`).

`gcc -Wall` highlights this clearly:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:24:22: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘changxr’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   24 |     changxr(arrsize, &arr[counter]);
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                      |
      |                      int *
prog.c:3:32: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
    3 | void changxr(int arrsize, int *arr[]);
      |                           ~~~~~^~~~~
```

Things to do:

- Simply pass the array and the length of the array to your function.
- Use a single level of indirection in your function definition, and when accessing the array.
- Use a [variable-length array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays).
- Use an auxiliary function for printing.
- Declare variables when you need them, in the correct scope.

You should also consider checking the return value of `scanf` is the expected number of *successful conversions*.

The refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changxr(int *a, size_t length)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void print_reverse(int *a, size_t length)
{
    printf("[ ");
    while (length--)
        printf("%d ", a[length]);
    printf("]\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t size;

    printf("Pick an array length: ");

    if (1 != scanf("%zu", &size) || size == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid length input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int array[size];

    printf("Enter %zu numbers:\n", size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (1 != scanf("%d", array + i)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid integer input.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Array (in reverse): ");
    print_reverse(array, size);

    changxr(array, size);

    printf("Array, Sorted (in reverse): ");
    print_reverse(array, size);
}
```